# BLTouch problem with pin deployment

Tags: creality-ender-3, bltouch

I bought and installed and uploaded the BLTouch firmware from Antclabs. When I click "level bed" it moves to homing the X and Y axes to 0 and to the middle but the probe does not extend (like its hidden all time) but when I turn on printer it lights up and do "dance" (self-test). I tried finding similar problems but every tutorial is for the Ender Pro; I have an Ender 3 (normal) not Pro or anything like that.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your wiring is done correctly? That would be my first thing to check.

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! I have helped you out with the question by re-formatting and added some explanations of what you wrote down, please evaluate the edit and adjust where you think adjustments need to be made. Correctly wiring is usually the problem in these cases, maybe you can add information on how you wired it up and which firmware you have installed, this should be done through an [edit].

Comment: I put the wires into the port near the screenn cable (like on tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xiy-oLLrB1k), same thing I did with firmware.

Comment: this is what happening https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ty93wuWkzAw&pp=ygUnQkwgVG91Y2ggbm90IGV4dGVuZGluZyB3aGVuIGF1dG8gaG9taW5n

Comment: Any additional info should be put in the question and **not** in the comments. Comments get deleted over time. Please [edit] and update your question.